# Get url links page in silverlight

Tags: c#

How do I get URL links page in Silverlight tools using HtmlAgilityPack.

For example:

```
List<string> urlList = new List<string>();

var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(responseBody);

foreach (var item in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link"))
{
    if (item.Attributes["href"] != null && item.Attributes["rel"].Value.EndsWith("stylesheet"))
        urlList.Add(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
    else { }
}
return urlList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Silver light pages does not have any html code lines so you can not see the page code to extract links from.